# Incline a sprite in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

Can I draw a sprite with an orientation of like 45 degrees? I'm developing a game which should display a sprite in different inclinations at different times.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate sprite in Libgdx according to the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#rotate-float-)

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I was calling it in the render method and so, I thought the rotate function is rotating the sprite continuously. I'm new to LibGDX and it took me a couple of days to figure out that render method is continuously being called.